# Generate unique id In PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create unique id in my project. I have used this

```
$key = md5(microtime().rand());
```

But I want to create unique id like this : `HPSEMP001` and so on `HPSEMP002`,`HPSEMP003`.

I am unable to do this please help me I am new in PHP

Comment: I want that every time when I call this 001,002 it return me

Comment: What will be after `HPSEMP999` ?

Comment: Keep track of generated ids in db or a file.

Comment: Also, if you wanted a truly unique id, use `uniqid()`.

Comment: @AlmaDo after HPSEMP999 this HPSEMP1000

Comment: Use an auto increment index and append HPSEMP to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a beginner, but I've tried this and it works:

```
$num = 0;
global $num;

function new_id() {
    global $num;
    return 'HPSEMP' . sprintf("%03d", $num++); 
}
```

Example of calling the function:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1500; $i++) {
    $new_id = new_id();
    echo "<br>$new_id";
}
```

Output:

```
HPSEMP000
HPSEMP001
HPSEMP002
HPSEMP003
.
.
.
HPSEMP997
HPSEMP998
HPSEMP999
HPSEMP1000
```

Alternatively, if you would like to save the code in a database or file, I have not tried this but it should work:

```
function new_id($num) {
        $num++;
        // * Code to save new number value in file or database
        return 'HPSEMP' . sprintf("%03d", $num++); 
    }

// * Code to retrieve id number from file or database and store it to $num
// * $num = previously stored id number
$new_id = new_id($num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create recursive function for generate random number, which is also checked in database if number is available in database or not.

In my example i have created different random departmentCode for customers using below code,

```
/**
 * Generate Random number and check if it is exist or not
 */
public function checkAndGenerateRandomNumber($customerId) {
    $number = sprintf("%04s", rand(1,9999));
    $response = ClassRegistry::init('Department')->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Department.customer_id' => $customerId, 'Department.code' => $number)));  
    if(isset($response) && !empty($response)) {
        $this->checkAndGenerateRandomNumber($customerId);
    } else {
        return $number;
    }
}
```